# Consider $[-1,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$. What is the minimum and infinimum of this set?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to write some proofs due to exam preparation. Is this one correct?

> Consider $[-1,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$. What is the minimum and infinimum of this set?

Edit: Lemma: It is well known that between two real numbers $a<b$ we have an irrational nummber(even infinetly many). This follows from the fact that because consider $(a,b)$\ $\mathbb{Q}$, $(a,b)$ contains uncountable many elements, and $\mathbb{Q}$ contains only countable many elements.

Infinimum: We are going to use the epsilon definition of the infimumum. Recall: Let $l$ be a lower bound and denote $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and if $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists x \in A$  such that $l+\epsilon \geq x \geq l$ then $l$ is the infinimum of the set $A$.
We claim $-1$ is the infinimum. Indeed $-1$ is a lower bound. But because $-1<-1+\epsilon$ and due to our lemma we can find for any $\epsilon>0$ an irrational number $x \in [-1,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ such that we have $-1<x<-1+\epsilon$

Minimum: We claim that there is no minimum. Assume there were a minimum. Let $x,y \in [-1,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $x$ be the minimum. Then $\forall y$ we have $x \leq y$. We know that $-1\neq  x$ because $-1$ is not irrational and $x$ must be in $[-1,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ and we also know that $-1\leq x$ . But then it is $-1< x$. With our lemma there exists another irrational number which is even smaller than $x$. A contradiction.

Comment: You can shorten the second part. If $\inf A \notin A$ then $A$ has no minimum.

Comment: Your lemma can be significant strengthened: Given $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, there exist infinitely many rational numbers and uncountably many irrational numbers in $(a,b)$. In your final line, your lemma does not apply because $x$ is irrational, but the argument still works, you just need a stronger lemma.

Comment: This looks good.  I didn't check the specific formula in your proof of the lemma, but this lemma is a well-known fact that you should be able to use.  And as @MartinR said, you can cut out most of your last paragraph by using that a minimum must be an infimum.  (But the argument in your last paragraph is a good explanation of *why* a minimum must be an infimum.)

Comment: I usually can't judge for myself how good my work is, that's why I ask, thanks for the help. The shortening seems to be extremely useful and I didn't notice it.

Comment: Your lemma apply only for rationales but $-1 + \varepsilon$  and $x$ may be irrationals.

Comment: I see this is a big problem

Comment: @Iwan5050 If you are allowed to use the fact that the interval $(a,b)$ (for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$) is uncountable and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, then it follows automatically that $(a,b)$ contains uncountably many irrational numbers

Comment: I have even prooven these two facts :)

Comment: @Iwan5050 What is it that you are referring to as a 'big problem'?

Comment: No it's not. I've fixed it.

Comment: The title says supremum.